# Installing HDF5 library on Cygwin: "make check" stuck at testswmr.sh, no error message

Tags: fortran, cygwin, gfortran, hdf5

I am currently installing the HDF5 library, more precisely the hdf5-1.10.0-patch1, on Cygwin, as I want to use it with Fortran. Following the instructions from the hdfgroup website
([here is the link](https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/current/src/unpacked/release_docs/INSTALL_Cygwin.txt)), I did the following:

```
./configure --enable-fortran
make > "out1_check.txt" 2> "warn1_check.txt" &
make check > "out2_check.txt" 2> "warn2_check.txt" &
```

The execution of the last command (`make check`) proceeds as it should, until it gets stuck. The process does not stop and something is happening (8-12% CPU are in use by sh.exe, already 39 hours of CPU time) but "out2_check.txt" looks like

```
Making check in src
...
[many successful checks]
...
============================
No need to test testlinks_env.sh again.
============================
============================
Testing testswmr.sh
```

Unfortunately, I do not have the output file from the first run of `make check`, but it did not contain more information on `Testing testswmr.sh`. There was never any error message.

So, what is this `testswmr.sh`, why does it get stuck and how can I finalize the installation process? Maybe I can skip the remaining checks and just proceed to `make install`?

Important note: an older version of HDF5 is already installed from the Cygwin repo. It does not seem to support Fortran however, so I decided to install the current version myself.

Available (and used) compilers are gcc and gfortran.

Comment: Did you try to look in `testswmr.sh` to find out what it does? (you should)

Comment: Well, I looked, but I do not really understand what t does in detail. It consists of several tests like    
    "## Writer test - test expanding the dataset",
    "## Remove test - test shrinking the dataset",
    "## Sparse writer test - test writing to random locations in the dataset",
etc.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, only Intel Fortran is supported on Windows. There is no Cygwin download here https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/release/obtain518.html and I have never come across a report of experience for Cygwin/Fortran/HDF5.

Your options:

1. Use Intel Fortran
2. Use Linux or Mac

Sorry

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Pierre ! I also thought Cygwin Fortran HDF5 is just not supported when I saw that the Cygwin-repo hdf5 package only includes C. However, based on [this instructions file](https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/current/src/unpacked/release_docs/INSTALL_Cygwin.txt) which I mentioned in the question above, it is possible to use the Unix source of hdf5 and install it manually from within Cygwin (and it is explicitly mentioned that one can use the `--enable-fortran` flag). That is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Ok, I did now check the linked instructions :-) This is still a barely used combination but the SWMR feature (single writer multiple readers) depends on the file system and may not work on FAT disks. I don't have references in memory but you should check SWMR compatibility. If it is not supported, no problem with the failing test but you should then not use the feature.

Comment: Thanks, @PierredeBuyl ! Right now I don't need SWMR, but I have managed to install the library as it is. With the right values of $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, $LIBRARY_PATH and the include flag, the code compiles and the output is perfectly fine. The way I resolved it: deinstall everything, reboot, install again with "make check > output_check.dat", "make install";) It was probably either the antivirus or the overdue Windows update which stopped the installation previously. However, if you add a note that one could still use Unix-source to install HDF5 for Fortran under Cygwin, I could accept your answer